# Create activity stack branch and clear it

Tags: android, android-activity

I know that similar questions were already asked many times but mine differs a bit.
For example I have Activity tree like A(root activity)-B-C-D-E (A launches B, B launches C etc). Also I have two buttons that can launch activities F and G, they are available everywhere (they are like menus and their launchMode="singleTask")

If one of "special" activities is called from B C D or E, then popup appears with a text like "Do you really want to ruin the booking process?". If user clicks "yes" then activity changes to "G", B C D and E activities should be cleared from the activity stack and pressing "back button" again returns user to activity A (or F, if G was called from F).

I could do this by setting flag "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" but it's not suitable because I need to somehow determine if G activity was called from one of B/C/D/E activities. If it is not (I mean it was called from A or F activity) then back button should be working as usual.

I have already tried:
broadcastRecievers through manifest file - I tried to call "finish()" on B C D E activities from another one. It is stupid a bit, because one of these could already been removed by GC.

"getCallingActivity()" method. Couldn't make it work. Wanted to compare if calling activity was one of B/C/D/E

"startActivityForResult(intent,result)" - it was not working (onActivityResult wasn't invoked), because I have "launchMode="singleTask" in my manifest file for F and G activities.

I have also tried to make a new Task for B-C-D-E tree. But realized that it even appears as a second task in launch menu.

I will really appreciate any help, even theoretical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using putExtra(). I passed string to activities F and G from B,C,D,E.
When F and G were called from each other and A I didn't pass anything.

By overwriting one method in F and G activities I achieved needed result:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (passedString != null) {
        final Intent a = new Intent(this, A.class);
        a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(a);
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what onResultReceived might be, but try:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
            Intent intent){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

...etc...

}
```

Just use the `intent.putExtra()`... for getting info from one activity to another. If you want it passed back use `this.setResult(int, intent)` within your "topmost" activity, and it will fire back. If you want it to fire all the way back to the beginning there is a flag for this too, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`. I think this prevents having to catch the result and then forwarding it again to the next lowest activity, could be wrong though.

Comment: Sorry! My memory cheated me. by saying "onResultReceived" I meant "OnActivityResult".
This method is not called when Activity which is going to send result is using "launchMode=singleTask" or "singleInstance".
So your solution is not going to work.